# Spy on jasmine function from an Angular library is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, function, jasmine, spy

I have an Angular library containing functions like "export function myFunction".
The project with the error have this library as a dependency and when I want to spy on the function, the error below is display:

```js
myFunction is not declared writable or has no setter
```

**Now the real world example**:

*A simple function from the library:*

```js
export function isNotEmptyString(value: any): value is string {
  return _.isString(value) && !_.isEmpty(value);
}
```

*The dts of this function once packaged:*

```js
export declare function isNotEmptyString(value: any): value is string;
```

To spy on the function, I must have an object at some point.
So I use a custom module import to achieve this.

*The spy on error:*

```js
import * as MyLibfrom 'my-lib';

const isNotEmptyStringSpy = spyOn(MyLib, 'isNotEmptyString').and.returnValue(false);
```

*And the error is:*

```js
isNotEmptyString is not declared writable or has no setter
```

*Now, if I use a `spyOnPropety`:*

```js
import * as MyLibfrom 'my-lib';

const isNotEmptyStringSpy = spyOnProperty(MyLib, 'isNotEmptyString').and.returnValue(() => false);
```

*And the new error is:*

```js
isNotEmptyString is not declared configurable
```

I also tried to use differents module inside the `tsconfig.json` compiler options.
Like `commonjs`, `CommonJS`, `ES2015` and `ESNext`.
There is no difference.

*tsconfig.json*

```js
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs"
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?
I am stuck with this :/

Thanks !

*Environment:*

```
"karma": "4.4.1"
"jasmine-core": "3.5.0"
"@angular/core": "9.0.5"
```